# finding customers who never ordered a pepperoni pizza

Tags: mysql, select

I  have a homework question please help with a little explanation so that I can understand.

You are writing a query, looking for all customers who have never ordered a pepperoni pizza. Which of these queries is the best match?

```
select distinct 
  c.customer_name 
from 
  customer c, 
  orders o 
where 
  o.customer_id = c.customer_id 
  and o.pizza_type = ‘pepperoni
```

---

```
select 
   c.customer_name 
from 
  customer c 
where 
  c.customer_id not in 
  (
     select 
       o.customer_id 
     from 
       orders o 
     where 
       o.pizza_type != ‘pepperoni’
  )
```

---

```
select distinct 
  c.customer_name 
from 
  customer c 
  left join orders o 
    on on.customer_id = c.customer_id 
    and o.pizza_type = ‘pepperoni’ 
where 
  o.pizza_type is null
```

---

```
select 
  c.customer_name 
from 
  customer c, 
  orders o 
where 
  o.customer_id = c.customer_id 
  and o.pizza_type = ‘pepperoni’ 
group by 
  c.customer_name 
having count(*) = 0
```

Comment: You won't find me, I ordered loads ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**3**, assuming that `on.customer_id` is a typo on your part that should be `o.customer_id`

Explanation:

**1**: Selects all customers who have ordered a pepperoni pizza.

**2**: Selects all customers who have only ever ordered a pepperoni pizza.

**3**: Selects all customers who have never ordered a pepperoni pizza.

**4**: Won't select anyone.

Comment: The OP asked for a "little explanation"?

Comment: `COUNT(*) = 0` means 0 rows, so won't pull back anything.

Answer (score 1):

- Option 1 returns the customers that has order a pizza
- Option 2 also returns the customers that has order a pizza (because `not in` and `!= ‘pepperoni’`) is true
- Option 3 returns the customers that has not order any pizzas. Because the final check, checks so that there are no 'pepperoni' on that customer (Correct!)
- Option 4 will not return anything

Answer (score 1):

1. This query selects the people that have ordered pepperoni, not those that haven't ordered pepperoni.
2. This also selects all the people that have ordered pepperoni. In the subquery, it selects all the orders that are not pepperoni and then (in the main query), it looks for all customers who are not in that subquery. So you obtain all the people who have not ordered "not pepperoni" pizzas, so that's everyone who has ordered pepperoni.
3. This is the correct query.
4. This won't return any results.